# Error on Websphere Application after restart

Tags: websphere

Can someone please advise how I can solve this issue. I am getting this error on my websphere application after restart.

```
SystemErr     R Thread[server.startup : 1,5,main] java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/derby/derby.log (Permission denied)
Booting Derby version The Apache Software Foundation - Apache Derby - 10.8.3.1 - (1452645): instance a816c00e-0170-ce1a-1169-ffff86094069 
on database directory /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppNode/databases/EJBTimers/peoplemember02/EJBTimerDB  with class loader com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader@9096b0eb 
Loaded from file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/derby/lib/derby.jar
java.runtime.version=pxa6470sr10fp5-20170421_01 (SR10 FP5)
java.fullversion=JRE 1.7.0 IBM J9 2.6 Linux amd64-64 Compressed References 20170407_343227 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that it lacks permission to the log file for the Apache Derby database that is used for EJB Persistent Timers.  Have you tried checking the permissions of the file and granting read/write access?

For example, to grant read & write access to all, you could do,

```
chmod a+rw /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/derby/derby.log
```

If this doesn't work, it is possible that permissions might be lacking to the folder which contains derby.log

Comment: I apologozed for giving incomplete details. The problem is there are no derby.log available or being created on the path mentioned. All permissions, groups and owners for the path are OK

Comment: Since there's no derby.log, you can try logging in to a terminal window as the appropriate user and touching that file.  If, as you say, all the perms, groups and owners are correct for the user running WAS, the touch will succeed.  After that, try rebooting the server to see the embedded derby instance can then write to that file.

Comment: @Rowe - There is a derby.log on DMGR server but no on derby.log on 2 cluster server -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1043 Nov 26  2013 derby.log

Comment: can this error also lead to this error? DATABASE = /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppNode/databases/EJBTimers/peoplemember02/EJBTimerDB), (DRDAID = null), Failed Statement is: ALTER TABLE EJBTIMER_TREG ADD PRIMARY KEY ("REGKEY")
ERROR 42Z93: Constraints 'SQL200312103622180' and 'SQL181102072832890' have the same set of columns, which is not allowed.

Comment: No, there is not a causal relationship between those two errors.  The ALTER TABLE error in your comment above is benign.  It's just the EJB persistent timer service wanting to ensure that REGKEY has a primary key constraint (it might not already be a primary key if someone had just upgraded versions of the app server).  If the exception is received indicating that constraint is already there, then it gets ignored and continues on.  It's unfortunate that it gets surfaced to the end user at all, causing unnecessary alarm.